# array.push in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

```
var conversations = new Array();
jQuery('.CChatWindow').each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).is(":visible") && jQuery(this).attr("data-conversationid") != 0) {
        alert(jQuery(this).attr("data-conversationid")); // returns 1 and 2
        conversations.push = (jQuery(this).attr("data-conversationid"));
    }
});
alert(conversations); // returns an empty string
```

Whats the problem with my code? array.push does not seem to work.
Thanks!

Comment: why are you trying to _overwrite_ `conversations.push` ?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
conversations.push = (jQuery(this).attr("data-conversationid"));
```

To

```
conversations.push( jQuery(this).attr("data-conversationid") );
```

`Array.push()` is a function call and not an assignment.

Comment: @Chris: Then you should click the checkmark next to this answer

Answer (score 3):

`array.push` is a function. Use it like:

```
conversations.push(jQuery(this).attr("data-conversationid"));
```